# Why does vim open in split window mode when I type :help, and what is the bottom window?

Tags: vim

If I open Vim and use `:help` to look up things, it always opens with this second window below which just takes up space and I have to close it. What is it and why is it doing this?

[image: Second window here - with the question marks]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That pesky window is just Vim's initial window, which you shouldn't worry about.

Vim's wording is sometimes a bit ambiguous but this is not the case. The current window is quite literally *split* in two, leaving you with two windows: the one you had before the split and a new one. Since Vim opens the new window above the current window by default, you get:

- the new help window above,
- the previous window below.

Initial state, one window:

```
+----------+
| 1        |
|          |
|          |
|          |
+----------+
```

Split:

```
:help
```

Final state, two windows:

```
+----------+
| 2        |
|          |
+----------+
| 1        |
+----------+
```

---

Vim's documentation is only ever useful *in Vim itself*, *while you are actually using it*. It is thus displayed in a split by default, so that you can refer to it while editing.

You are apparently doing `:help` right after starting Vim, without editing anything, so you get the standard split… and your previous empty window lying around, which is totally fine and expected.

If you don't want that behaviour, you can create this file (and the necessary subdirectories):

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/qf.vim
```

and put this in it:

```
only
```

See `:help :only` and `:help ftplugin`.